# Tocloft and List of Figures: Get rid of title and begin right at the top

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

I am using `tocloft` to create an List of Figures. Now I would like to get rid of title and the list of figure should begin right at the top after the chapter title. I know the following is not a minimal example, but it should be understandable.

In the preamble I have this:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Abb. }
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Abb. 10\quad}
%\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2cm}
\renewcommand\cftfigfont{\footnotesize} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftnodots}%punkte im abb. verzeichnis.
\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
```

And between begin and end

```
\begin{document}

% in between there are many figures... 

\renewcommand\listfigurename{}
\chapter{Abbildungsnachweise}

It should begin here.

\listoffigures

\end{documen}
```

[image: Example of output]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling `\listoffigures`, use

```
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{lof}% Print List of Figures
\makeatother
```

directly, or remove the header construction suggested by `tocloft`:

```
{\makeatletter
\let\@cftmakeloftitle\relax
\listoffigures% Print List of Figures
\makeatother}
```

The latter (perhaps preferred) solution stems from the definition if `\listoffigures` in [`tocloft.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.dtx) (note the `\@cftmakeloftitle` that is not needed, since you're providing your own):

```
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
  \@cfttocstart
  \par
  \begingroup
    \parindent\z@ \parskip\cftparskip
    \@cftmakeloftitle
    \if@cfttocbibind
      \@cftdobiblof
    \fi
    \@starttoc{lof}%
  \endgroup
  \@cfttocfinish}
\fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have a follow-up question. [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51481/tocloft-and-list-of-figure-change-line-spacing-between-listings)