# Tocloft and list of figure: Change Line Spacing between listings

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing, tocloft

This not the same question as [here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/784/how-to-change-the-line-spacing-in-my-list-of-figures) 
While creating a list of figures with tocloft the way shown in the example, I would like to control the line spacing between the listings of the figures. With something like

```
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
```

or similar. Here is the example.

(Preamble):

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Abb. }
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Abb. 10\quad}
%\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2cm}
\renewcommand\cftfigfont{\footnotesize} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftnodots}%punkte im abb. verzeichnis.
\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
```

And:

```
\begin{document}

% in between there are many figures... 

\chapter{Abbildungsnachweise}
{\makeatletter
\let\@cftmakeloftitle\relax
%\@starttoc{lof}% Print List of Figures
\listoffigures
\makeatother} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redefine the length `\cftbeforefigskip`:

```
\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{20pt}
```